# Import excel file to angular - "Unexpected token P in JSON at position 0" error

Tags: c#, angular, excel, webapi

I'm using webapi project in c# and angular
I implemented a function in the controller that exports an excel file, and another funtion in the angular service to import this excel.

The c# funtion works great , it creates a new excel, and saves it into some path.

The problem happens in the angular: Unexpected token P in JSON at position 0

Here is my code:

C# controller:

```
        [HttpGet]
        [Route("downloadProducts/{userID}")]
        public HttpResponseMessage DownloadProducts(int userID)
        {
                var pathToExcel=WriteExcel.GetPathToProducts(userID);
                var buffer = File.ReadAllBytes(pathToExcel);
                var stream = new MemoryStream(buffer);
                var result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK)
                {
                    Content = new ByteArrayContent(stream.ToArray())
                };
                result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition =
                    new System.Net.Http.Headers.ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment")
                    {
                        FileName = "products.xlsx"
                    };
                result.Content.Headers.ContentType =
                    new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");

                return result;
        }
```

Angular service:

```
  downloadFile (userID:number):Observable<Blob>{
    return this.http.get<Blob>(`${this.url}/downloadProducts/${userID}`);
 }
```

Componenet.TS

```
const EXCEL_TYPE = 'application/octet-stream';
  this.productsService.downloadloadFile(this.user.userID).subscribe(data=>{
        var file = new Blob([data], { type: EXCEL_TYPE });
        this.href =   window.URL.createObjectURL(file);
        setTimeout(() => {
          console.log(this.href);
        }, 500);
        window.open(this.href);
})
```

What should I fix?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here in above function use MIME type **text/csv** instead of **application/octet-stream** it can download file using .xlsx extension.

Do not convert it to Blob try without it.

```
 downloadFile (userID:number):Observable<any>{
    return this.http.get<any>(`${this.url}/downloadProducts/${userID}`);
 }
```